# nginx try_files with s3 bucket and proxy_pass for html pages without extension

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket that contains directories and html files. I'm using nginx in front of the bucket and have configured a proxy_pass to the bucket, which works fine. I want clean URLs without the html extension, and for these URLs to resolve properly. For example, instead of `foo.com/bar/my-file-name.html`, this must be accessible at `foo.com/bar/my-file-name`

The primary question here is how to prevent requiring the .html at the end of every URL. As in, I want nginx to handle routing each requests and try looking for a file with the .html extension, and then return it.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to force nginx to `try_files` like I would on a non-S3 site. When I do try and add any configuration of `try_files`, it breaks the site by returning HTTP 500 errors on all paths.

For comparison, here is the configuration that works great on a non-S3 backed site (with the files on the server itself):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
}

location @htmlext {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
}
```

My goal is to replicate this behavior with a `proxy_pass` to an S3 bucket and force it to try filenames with an .html extension other than `index.html`, which works out of the box.

Here is my current configuration that works great, minus any html files other than `index.html`:

```
location / {

     proxy_pass my-bucket.s3.blahblah/;
}
```